# user controller passing value display result based on the function

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

how to display the result on page on aspx to the user controller? the result have been done by the function. how to passing the value?
i have a user controller name as ddMenu inside have a labal lblQty, and on my cartpage.aspx have done the function and display a result on labal1

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblQty" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** You can pass the value to the usercontrol using a property in usercontrol.

In the UserControl add a public property and set that propertyfrom Page. Here I am saving the value in `ViewState` so that it persists between postbacks. In usercontrol (ddMenu.ascx.cs):

```
public string MyLabelText
{ 
    get
    {
        if(ViewState["LabelQty"] != null)
            return ViewState["LabelQty"].ToString();
        return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
         ViewState["LabelQty"] = value;
    }
}
```

And in Page code (**Cart.aspx.cs**) set it like this:

```
myddMenu.MyLabelText = lblQty.Text;
```

Now you can access the value in **usercontrol**:

```
//I have a label "Label1" in usercontrol 
Label1.Text = MyLabelText;
```

Comment: cannot assign to the mylabeltext because it is a method group wht error?

Comment: @Mickey - Please see the edit. For method, use `myddMenu.MyLabelText("My Text");`. Or use the property.

Comment: why is labelQty? i need a simple one

Comment: You want to display the text in usercontrol and in your user control the label ID is "lblQty". You can replace it with whatever label you want to display the text.

Comment: @Mickey - I have simplified the answer.